# How do I find this value for the feedback fraction?

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator, feedback, negative-feedback, positive-feedback

[image]

How exactly do I find this value for the feedback fraction Beta? Thank you. \$\omega_0\$ here is the natural frequency calculated as \$\omega_0\$ = 1/RC and s is the complex frequency.

Answer (score 1):

It`s very simple:

The feedback factor is nothing else than a frequency-dependent voltage divider Z2/(Z1+Z2) with Z1 as a series combination and Z2 as a parallel combination of the given impedances (R resp. 1/wC).

This passive part forms the most simple form of an RC-bandpass.